# More flexible SEO URLs in OSCommerce?

Tags: mod-rewrite, oscommerce

New OScommerce user.

I've been fiddling around with Chemo's Ultimate SEO add-on the last few days. I've mostly got it working (minus one bizarre redirect loop for category pages?) but I'm a little disappointed in the limited options for formatting URLs.

I'm seeing:

```
 http://www.website.com/category-awesomeproduct-p-1735.html
```

When we'd really like to do something more in line with:

```
http://www.website.com/category/awesomeproduct
```

What are my options? Am I out of luck?

I fear that the stock URL parameters are rigidly defined and that there's no way to hide the less friendly ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this for quite awhile, and receiving no answers here, I believe the answer is: no

The view controller expects that data and it can't be omitted, even with customizations installed.